# Maximally placement of $n$ vectors in $d$-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to solve the **following problem**:

Given $n$ vectors $x_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d} (\mathbb{C}^{d})$ of unit norm ($\Vert x \Vert$ = 1) find the maximally orthogonal placement of them.

By maximally orthogonal, I mean that something like that $\sum_{i \neq j}^{n} | (x_i, x_j) |$ or $\sum_{i \neq j}^{n}  (x_i, x_j)^2$ is minimized.
Second option is simpler to optimize.

For $n \leq d$ answer is obvious, one can place vectors along the coordinate axes, and they will be mutually orthogonal.

However, for $n > d$ task is more complicated.

My logic would be to solve the constrained optimization problem of the form:
$$
L(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \min_{x_i} \left[\sum_{i \neq j}^{n}  (x_i, x_j)^2 + \lambda_i \sum_i ((x_i, x_i) - 1)\right]
$$
Here $ \lambda_i$ are the Lagrange multipliers. However, the resulting system of equations for stationary points is nonlinear:
$$
\frac{dL}{d x_i} = 2 \sum_{i \neq j}^{n}  (x_i, x_j) x_i + \lambda_i  x_i
$$
How would you suggest to proceed further?

Comment: The search term "Grassmannian Subspace Packing" might be useful. Of course, some of those results minimize $\max_{i \neq j}(x_i,x_j)$ instead of $\sum_{i \neq j}|(x_i,x_j)|$ or $\sum_{i \neq j}(x_i,x_j)^2$.